# Need assistance regarding dispatch_sync and dispatch_async

Tags: ios, objective-c, grand-central-dispatch

```
- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info {

    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:^{}];

    [self.navigationController.tabBarController.view addSubview:self.waitingView];

    dispatch_queue_t currentQueue = dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0);
    dispatch_async(currentQueue, ^{

        self.originalImgFromPicker = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];

        CGSize size = self.originalImgFromPicker.size;
        if (size.width > 320)
        {
            size.height /= (size.width / 320);
            size.width = 320;
        }

        UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(size);
        [self.originalImgFromPicker drawInRect:CGRectMake(0,0,size.width,size.height)];
        self.resizedImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
        self.originalImgFromPicker = nil;

        NSData *resizedImageBinary = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(self.resizedImage, 1.0);

        self.resizedImageBinaryString = [NSString base64StringFromData:resizedImageBinary length:resizedImageBinary.length];

        dispatch_sync(currentQueue, ^{
            [self.waitingView removeFromSuperview];
        });
    });
}
```

I am processing the image and during this I am blocking the UI with transparent view with activity indicator.

but this `self.waitingView` disappearing take long time then it should.

When the image processing is in progress the UI actually get block by `self.waitingView` means when I try to tap controls behind nothing work but when image process in async block get done `self.waitingView` still remain on screen and when I try to tap any control it responds.

If I do nothing it take some time to disappear.

I want to do this in snappy way, what I am doing wrong in code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

UI operations should be done in the main queue

change the code

```
         dispatch_sync(currentQueue, ^{
            [self.waitingView removeFromSuperview];
        });
```

to

```
        dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            [self.waitingView removeFromSuperview];
        });
```

so u r method should look like

```
    - (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info {

    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:^{}];

    [self.navigationController.tabBarController.view addSubview:self.waitingView];

    dispatch_queue_t currentQueue = dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0);
    dispatch_async(currentQueue, ^{

        self.originalImgFromPicker = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];

        CGSize size = self.originalImgFromPicker.size;
        if (size.width > 320)
        {
            size.height /= (size.width / 320);
            size.width = 320;
        }

        UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(size);
        [self.originalImgFromPicker drawInRect:CGRectMake(0,0,size.width,size.height)];
        self.resizedImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
        self.originalImgFromPicker = nil;

        NSData *resizedImageBinary = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(self.resizedImage, 1.0);

        self.resizedImageBinaryString = [NSString base64StringFromData:resizedImageBinary length:resizedImageBinary.length];

        dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            [self.waitingView removeFromSuperview];
        });
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace

```
dispatch_sync(currentQueue, ^{
        [self.waitingView removeFromSuperview];
    });
```

with

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        [self.waitingView removeFromSuperview];
    });
```